# IIS 7 - changed from localNetwork to defaultapppool?

Tags: iis-7, permissions

Ive updated my process Model Identity from `NetworkService` to `ApplicationPoolIdentity`.

However,

What permissions did `NetworkService` had before and to what ?
What was his security permissions to the asp.net ?

and how do I **clone** the **previuos** permissions to the  `ApplicationPoolIdentity` account ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You should look here for an explanation of Application Pool identities:

http://learn.iis.net/page.aspx/624/application-pool-identities/

> NETWORKSERVICE is a built-in Windows identity. It doesn't require a
>   password and has only user privileges; that is, it is relatively
>   low-privileged. Running as a low-privileged account is a good security
>   practice because then a software bug can't be used by a malicious user
>   to take over the whole system.

Comment: , But on 7.5 the default is ApplicationPoolIdentity  so HOW can I know what permissions this account has ? Does he takes all the permissions from the networkService ?

Comment: The ApplicationPoolIdentity will have the same network permissions as NetworkService since it uses the machine account (<domainname>\<machinename>$).  However, the rights on the local machine are limited to whatever is ACLed for that user.  The ApplicationPoolIdentity is a unique user that's created with each application pool so it will be limited to whatever you give it rights to access.  If you want to replicate what NetworkService has access to, you'll need to examine the existing permissions.